# X-cart shopping page is showing as blank

Tags: x-cart

For site http://www.truly-organic-clothing.com, shop tab: http://www.truly-organic-clothing.com/shop is showing as blank.

Please provide the possible solution to fix

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear templates cache (var/templates_c).

Also check var/log folder for error logs.